Npm run dev works only once with Vite
I made a Vue project using Vite using, npm create vue@latest and I used npm install then npm run dev as usual to host my app and it worked properly.
But the problem is when I exited the cmd and re-opened it later, and I faced this problem when running npm run dev
 D:\APP\Front-End Development\vue-project
 λ npm run dev

 > vue-project@0.0.0 dev
 > vite

 failed to load config from D:\APP\Front-End Development\vue-project\vite.config.js
 error when starting dev server:
 Error: The service was stopped
    at D:\APP\Front-End Development\vue-project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:968:34
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (D:\APP\Front-End Development\vue- project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:622:9)
    at Socket.afterClose (D:\APP\Front-End Development\vue- project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:613:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1376:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

I searched more about this issue and found that I have to delete node_modules and package-lock.json and re-install them then re-run npm run dev again to run the server correctly.
So I'm done with that; deleting and reinstalling those folders whenever I want to host my app on the localhost.
And I'm looking for a way to permanently solve this problem without deleting and reinstalling. Is it possible?
I'm using Vite version 5.3.1 and Vue 3.4.29, and Node.js version 20.5.0.
These are package.json and vite.config.js files:
package.json:
{
  "name": "vue-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.4.29",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.8.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.23.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "sass-embedded": "^1.79.4",
    "vite": "^5.3.1"
  }
}


vite.config.json:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})



When you look to the error, there is an additional space in the paths, e.g., "vue- project" instead of "vue-project". Copy mistake?

@sicreep copy mistake yeah

Zein, you can [edit] your question to fix any issues.
